# Cannot click on login screen on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, login, mouse, dell, tap-to-click

I am facing a weird issue on my laptop. Whenever I boot into my system I'm not able to click anywhere on the login screen. Keyboard works as expected and I can move cursor on the login screen but cannot click anything neither setting drop-down nor accessibility option. I have searched for this issue on various sites but it is not mentioned anywhere.
If anyone have any idea of why this is happening or if there is a way to resolve this issue, your help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

**Please note:**

1. I'm not having login issue or anything. All the other functionality works as expected and I can login to my system just from keyboard. It's just that that click functionality of cursor seems to disabled at the login screen.
2. I have recently replaced the Windows with Ubuntu 20.04 on my dell laptop.

---

As for my **System Info**, It is:

Dell Inspiron 15 7572
i5 8th Gen
500 GB SSD
16 GB RAM
Nvidia Mx150 Graphic card

---

**EDIT**
I noticed the following log while rebooting my system
"failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1"

I think this might be related to abnormal behaviour of cursor as mentioned above.

Comment: What pointing device are you using?

Comment: Just a touchpad

Comment: Check the connection of the wires for the touchpad.

Comment: Are you using separate buttons for clicking or are you trying to use the functionality of some touchpads to generate a click when you tap a finger on them quickly, and a right click when you tap with two fingers? The latter typically requires a special driver.

Comment: Yeah it's the right click from touchpad using two finger or any other action involving clicking except hovering. Also there is no issue with the touchpad itself. It works perfectly after logging in to my system.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403291/touchpad-click-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-login-screen This might help. I didn't actually try the method in the answer to get touchpad tap working, but I realized that touchpad hardware click works on the login screen.